# Repaint/refinish worn fridge handle

Tags: paint, appliances, repainting

My fridge handle is worn to the point that the foam is exposed and it can't be wiped clean. How can I refinish it with a durable finish? I'm assuming anything with a solvent would destroy the foam.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 2):

Using you model number you can order an exact replacement handle from the manufacturer.

Comment: Not to be antagonistic, but this does not answer the question. Although a replacement would certainly create a new finish that may be only as durable as the original, it would not necessarily be more durable as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reasonably handy, you could consider to purchase some light weight fiberglass, the type commonly used to cover radio control aircraft. It's measured in ounces per square square yard. You can find one half ounce per square yard up to 3 or 4 considered as hobby weight. The heavier stuff is what you'll find for boat repair, auto repair and the like.

You'd want to use a quality epoxy resin to avoid destroying the foam. The good stuff is pricey and you could get away with thinning down some ordinary hobby grade epoxy, especially if you plan to paint the repair. Cut the fabric to size perhaps long thin strips from top to bottom, with overlap. Paint on the epoxy resin, push the fabric into the resin on the handle, then stipple the brush over the fabric to embed more resin into the fabric and to ensure full coverage. Bubbles will show up clearly and can be stippled out with a bit of patience.

After the epoxy cures, it can be sanded as desired and painted to taste.

Don't get five minute stuff if you go the hobby route. You'll get better results with industrial grade epoxy resin, but as I noted, it's expensive. I think I paid US$65 for a quart of West Systems epoxy and hardener, but it's glass clear and wonderfully strong.

Comment: I pay about $100 for a gallon of 105 base + fast or slow hardener plus the set of pumps.  I shop at chandleries that serve tradesmen, not the sort that shake down boat owners *coughwestmarinecough*.  It's so versatile I wouldn't dream of not owning it.  I use it for so many things.

Comment: This particular shop I use is about the only one that has the good stuff and they primarily serve tradesman. I'm lucky they don't have a restriction against selling at the retail level, as other shops have done in this area. I, too have found the stuff to be extremely versatile. I won't go to the business which causes you respiratory difficulty for the reason you note.

Answer (score 0):

Spray paint it with epoxy paint from a "rattle can", give it a few coats for durability. Simple and effective, it will look good too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an acrylic epoxy that is used to renovate counter tops, there is also similar for redoing a bathroom tub - you could go that route.

However time and effort - look up your model number then use a search engine for the [model#] door handle . You should find appliance parts to replace it and that is the cheaper and easier route, it might set you back a whopping $20 bucks. I forget what mine cost but it was fairly cheap..

Of Course if you ever watched the Red Green show - you would know this can be done with duct tape for less. :-)